# how to get command result of git push

Tags: shell

I want to trigger jenkins after push,write my shell script like this:

```
result=`git push|grep up`

echo "result:$result"

if [[$result != "Everything up-to-date"]] then
  curl http://192.168.2.200:8080/view/gradle/job/soa-report-consumer/build
fi
```

but the result is null,by the way the git have no post-push hook.What should I do to get result of `git push`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `git push` will go to `stderr`.

Do it by redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` with `git push 2>&1 | grep up`.

(By the way, you should improve your `grep` - like `grep "up-to-date"`, since it could match any string `up`, not necessarily the result you want)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$ status=$(git push 2>&1)
$ echo $status
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but *code-only* or *try-this* answers are not as helpful as those with a short concise explanation of why you did what you have done. Additionally, *try-this* answers imply you are unsure if the answer is correct and that the questioner should just *try-this* and see if it works. No dings, just helpful advice.

Comment: Thanks. Advice Taken.

Comment: Adding a short explanation describing capturing the result of the *command substitution* redirected to `stderr` in `status` may make the question worthy of additional upvotes. It would for me.